# RTK Query vs CreateAysncThunk updating state

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I built a project a little while ago using Redux Toolkit and CreateAsyncThunk. I am now working on a new project using RTK Query.

In the [documentation](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-7-rtk-query-basics) for RTK Query:

> Currently,  is specifically importing useSelector,
> useDispatch, and useEffect, reading posts data and loading state from
> the store, and dispatching the fetchPosts() thunk on mount to trigger
> the data fetch. The useGetPostsQueryHook replaces all of that!

Now previously, I sometimes changed the global state directly in a CreateAsyncThunk.fulfilled

```
let user = sessionStorage.getItem("user");

const initialState: AuthState = {
  user: user ? user : null,
  message: "",
  isError: false,
  isLoading: false,
  isSuccess: false,
};


export const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    reset: (state) => {
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.isSuccess = false;
      state.isError = false;
      state.message = "";
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(Signin.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
        state.isError = false;
        state.isSuccess = false;
      })
      .addCase(Signin.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        //updating the state of user as soon as creatAsyncThunk finishes no additional dispatch
        state.user = action.payload.RefreshToken;
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isError = false;
        state.isSuccess = true;
      })
      .addCase(Signin.rejected, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isError = true;
        state.isSuccess = false;
      });
  },
});
```

Where I need clarification is in an [auth example](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/tree/master/examples/query/react/authentication?from-embed=&file=/src/features/auth/Login.tsx:2013-2550) for RTK query they use RTK query with dispatch, they just dispatch the result, is there no way and or is it just bad practice to change the global state from an RTK Query. (comments are my own)

```
 <Button
          isFullWidth
          onClick={async () => {
            try {
              //call use query
              const user = await login(formState).unwrap()
              //additional dispatch if you want to actually change the state in store
              dispatch(setCredentials(user))
              navigate('/')
            } catch (err) {
              toast({
                status: 'error',
                title: 'Error',
                description: 'Oh no, there was an error!',
                isClosable: true,
              })
            }
          }}
          colorScheme="green"
          isLoading={isLoading}
        >
```

Is the normal flow going to be dispatching the results of an RTK query and is there no way to have the RTK query itself change/update the state from the Query so that you are really getting rid of the use Dispatches like how I am understanding the original quote in the documentation? Maybe you where never supposed to do it the way I was with creatAsyncThunk in the first place?

EDIT:
On the issue of can you, I suppose you can just dispatch from a transferResponse in a query or mutation after its finished and then only have to call the function, and this to me seemed like the way you would be expected to use RTK Query, but no examples showed this or at least I did not see it in the docs, and maybe its best practice to keep fetching and state logic totally separate?